# Rails Administrate: Cannot customise controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate, rails-administrate

I'm using Rails Administrate and want to override the `new` action on a controller. [The documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/main/docs/customizing_controller_actions.md) suggests this is straightforward. However, the application seems to ignore my override and goes straight to rendering `new.html.erb` instead of going through my override of the `new` method:

Controller:

```
class MyOrderController < Administrate::ApplicationController

    def valid_action?(name, resource = resource_class)
      %w[edit destroy].exclude?(name.to_s) && super
    end

    def new
      @orders = Order.find_by(property: params[:property])
    end
end
```

View:

```
<div>
<%= @orders.each { |order| %>
  <%=  order.id  %>
<% } %>
</div>
```

In particular, when going to `/orders/new`, the application doesn't go through my custom `new` action first, causing an error because @orders is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, cause was a silly syntax error: `end` statement was in the wrong place:

```
module MyModule do
  class MyOrderController < Administrate::ApplicationController

    def valid_action?(name, resource = resource_class)
      %w[edit destroy].exclude?(name.to_s) && super
    end
  
  end <-- in wrong place

    def new <-- outside the scope of Controller 
      @orders = Order.find_by(property: params[:property])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi there :-) Since you solved this, do you mind marking the answer as accepted, so that it's clear that no follow-up is needed? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Will do, it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Oh, I see. No worries. Thank you for explaining :-)